# ¿Como recargar la tabla con ajax despues del success?

Tags: laravel, ajax, crud

Estoy intentando hacer un crud con ajax sin datatables, pero al agregar un  registro no me recarga la tabla. He intentado buscar varios ejemplos pero todos lo hacen con datatables y la idea es hacer mi propia tabla.

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('#agregar').click(function(){
   $('#modal-agregar').modal('show');
});

$('#btn-agregar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var tabla = $("#table-movies");
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var premiere = $('#premiere').val();
    

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/peliculas/guardar",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          title: title,
          premiere: premiere
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('#modal-agregar').modal('hide');
         $('#form-peliculas')[0].reset();
         tabla.fnDraw();
      },
      error: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

No veo la info de tu tabla así que utilicé una tabla genérica.

```html
<table id="table" class="table container-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan="4">Tabla de películas</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Premiere</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

1. En Ajax yo lo utilizo con el Done, Fail y Always:

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/peliculas/guardar",
            data: {
                   title: title,
                   premiere: premiere
            },
            dataType: "json"
        })
            .done(function (response, jqXHR, textStatus) {                                  
                    $("#table tbody").append(
                        "<tr><td>" + response.id + "</td><td>" + response.titulo + "</td><td>" + response.premiere + "</td></tr>"
                    );
                    form.trigger("reset");
                 
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.info("Error en el Servidor. Revise los logs.");
            })
            .always(function () {
                console.info("Ejecutado correctamente");
            });
```

**Explicación**
El response obtenido en el done() lo añado dentro del tbody con el append.
Este código lo he probado yo en un pequeño proyecto y si funciona.

*Te recomiendo el DataTables*